# Command Line for Final Cut Pro Import?

Tags: terminal, command-line, automator, final-cut-pro

Is there a command that I can use for importation of files into `Final Cut Pro`?  I tried this next command but `Command-O` is not the way to import files.

```
open -g -a "/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app" /Volumes/D2/converted/20190811_000009_14E7_00408CFA958C.mp4
```

Is there a way to do this?  I need to automate importation of many files at 1am.

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the creators behind CommandPost.

CommandPost is a free and open source Mac application that allows you to seriously speed up your creative editing process through powerful and customisable automation tools. Think Apple’s Automator, with a little bit of BetterTouchTool and Keyboard Maestro thrown in, but specifically designed for creative professionals. It's a fork of Hammerspoon - and everything is scripted in Lua.

The way we get files into Final Cut Pro using our watch folder functionality is via the Pasteboard. We copy the file path to the pasteboard, then trigger a Paste operation in Final Cut Pro. Here's a link to the specific code:

https://github.com/CommandPost/CommandPost/blob/develop/src/plugins/finalcutpro/watchfolders/media/MediaFolder.lua#L710

You can control CommandPost via Lua-based plugins, AppleScript, URL and Terminal commands - so you could definitely work out a way to do this at a specific time rather than via Watch Folders.

We have a fairly active Facebook Group, and you're also more than welcome to contact us via the details on the CommandPost site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: emailing you now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [CommandPost](https://commandpost.io/) which has a Watch Folders function. I've never used this software, so I'm not sure of its full capabilities. It may be a good place to start.

*Disclaimer*: I have no financial or personal ties to CommandPost.io.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Just says Watch Folders and the docs aren't there to explain anything.  But looks interesting.  Do you know if I can cron these items?  I'd like to schedule them somehow.

Comment: Never used it. Just Google searched for automating Final Cut and found [this link](http://www.fcp.co/forum/4-final-cut-pro-x-fcpx/27873-is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-import-process-in-final-cut-pro-x), which lead to CommandPost. Good Luck!